# Python scikit learn pca.explained_variance_ratio_ cutoff

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

When choosing the number of principal components (k), we choose k to be the smallest value so that for example, 99% of variance, is retained.

However, in the Python Scikit learn, I am not 100% sure `pca.explained_variance_ratio_ = 0.99` is equal to "99% of variance is retained"?  Could anyone enlighten?  Thanks.

- The Python Scikit learn PCA manual is here

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Yes, you are nearly right.  The `pca.explained_variance_ratio_` parameter returns a vector of the variance explained by each dimension.  Thus `pca.explained_variance_ratio_[i]`  gives the variance explained solely by the i+1st dimension.

You probably want to do `pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum()`.  That will return a vector `x` such that `x[i]` returns the *cumulative* variance explained by the first i+1 dimensions.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

np.random.seed(0)
my_matrix = np.random.randn(20, 5)

my_model = PCA(n_components=5)
my_model.fit_transform(my_matrix)

print my_model.explained_variance_
print my_model.explained_variance_ratio_
print my_model.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum()
```

---

```
[ 1.50756565  1.29374452  0.97042041  0.61712667  0.31529082]
[ 0.32047581  0.27502207  0.20629036  0.13118776  0.067024  ]
[ 0.32047581  0.59549787  0.80178824  0.932976    1.        ]
```

So in my random toy data, if I picked `k=4` I would retain 93.3% of the variance.

Comment: One more question: when we do PCA(n_components=1), the scikit learn "PCA" commands perform the "Compute covariance matrix from the normalized data" & "Use single value decomposition (SVD) to compute eigenvectors "?  I don't see any where to choose other methods to compute eigenvectors in the Python scikit learn PCA module.

Comment: I think some "*e-int" went missing from first members of the copied results. That might be confusing. Otherwise, This is great! +1

Comment: @AChervony, not sure what you mean.

Comment: You can disregard it, just thanks and +1. The numbers I got were showing in scientific notation. E.g. 3.45e-4, so the scale of the result seemed wrong. All in all: 'Thanks!'

Comment: isn't it enough to sum, like sum(my_model.explained_variance_ratio_)? why cumsum?

Comment: @kilgoretrout If you want to see the intermediate sums you have to do cumsum.  `pca.explained_variance_ratio_.sum()` will always give you 1.0 if you are doing a full-rank PCA (same number of PCs as original dimensions).

Comment: @chubaka you will probably not find any other place doing the eigen_vector calc as it is really a single classical implementation available through LAPACK in FORTRAN.

Answer (score 56):

Although this question is older than 2 years i want to provide an update on this.
I wanted to do the same and it looks like sklearn now provides this feature out of the box.

As stated in the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)

> if 0 < n_components < 1 and svd_solver == ‘full’, select the number of components such that the amount of variance that needs to be explained is greater than the percentage specified by n_components

So the code required is now

```
my_model = PCA(n_components=0.99, svd_solver='full')
my_model.fit_transform(my_matrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me with even less typing in the PCA section.
The rest is added for convenience. Only 'data' needs to be defined in an earlier stage.

```
import sklearn as sl
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler as ss
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA 

st = ss().fit_transform(data)
pca = PCA(0.80)
pc = pca.fit_transform(st) # << to retain the components in an object
pc

#pca.explained_variance_ratio_
print ( "Components = ", pca.n_components_ , ";\nTotal explained variance = ",
      round(pca.explained_variance_ratio_.sum(),5)  )
```